# How to add image map in css?

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I have a question regarding image map. Now I have a image on my .xhtml page which uses image map somewhat like this

```
<img src="images/friends.png" usemap="#guys" />
<map name="guys">
            <area shape="rect" coords="6,1,12,14" alt="Jason"
                href="http://www.jason.com" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="19,2,38,15" alt="jay"
                href="http://www.jay.com" />
        </map>
```

is there a way I can add the map name contents in css? is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why on Earth are you using an image map?

Comment: I updated my question with the img tag. If you can help me with css that would be great. Thanks Oscar

Comment: Are you asking if you can target the <map> with CSS?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question with the image tag too if you can help me with some other tech.

Comment: What do you mean "add the map name contents in css"? What's the functionality you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

ImageMaps are a holdover from a bygone era. Html 5 canvas stuff is the way to go if you can push that envelope. If you can't, what we have done in the past is layered absolutely positioned, block-displayed blank anchor tags over an image. Works as well or better than an image map, especially if you are using it for stuff like popups on a map.

Comment: Why is putting anchors over an image better than just using an imagemap? At best, it does the same thing, and as far as I know, you would be limited to rectangular shaped hotspots, unlike an imagemap. There are certainly ways to achieve the same thing without an imagemap - you can keep your own table of vector data, and figure out for yourself what to do on a click or mouseover -- but why not just use the built-in construct if it already does what you need to do? It's simple and works with every browser.